# What would be the size of the outer asteroid belt in this system?

Tags: solar-system, gas-giants, asteroids

I am following the Artifexia-like system building with the calculator. Per the calculator, my system looks like this:
[image: Solar System Calculation]

I am having trouble calculating the inner and outer limits of the second asteroid belt. I haven't seen any calculations for an outer belt and this one is supposed to be controlled by a Giant closer to the sun that it. How do I calculate it?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the tool.  Are the 3 lines for 19.33, 38.53, and 76.93 all supposed to be associated with the second Asteroid Belt, or is only the first for that and the next two are just empty orbits?

Comment: @Michael Richardson Each line is a separate stable orbit. I left the two after the belt free, cause I was worried that putting a belt closer to outer giants would cause issues.